# dependson option does not work in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

## Data File

Name of the data file = toto.rmd

Contains following:

````
##1st

```{r clock, cache=TRUE}
x <- 600
x
```


##2nd

```{r, cache=TRUE, cache.path="toto_cache/", dependson="clock"}

x+5
```
````

## Problem

The second chunk is not being updated. Previously x was 500, after updating it to 600, I get following after `knit HTML` in RSTUDIO:

> ```
> 1st
> x <- 600
> x
> ## [1] 600
> 2nd
> x+5
> ## [1] 505
> ```

What am I missing here?

## Session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-3   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.4       evaluate_0.5.5    
 [5] formatR_0.10       grid_3.0.3         gtable_0.1.2       htmltools_0.2.4   
 [9] knitr_1.6          labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-29        munsell_0.4.2     
[13] plyr_1.8.1         proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.11.0       
[17] reshape2_1.2.2     rmarkdown_0.2.64   scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2     
[21] tools_3.0.3        yaml_2.1.10       
>
```

Comment: Can you attach the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @Dason I've included the sessionInfo()

Comment: I got it: `cache.path="toto_cache/"` should be added in the 1st chunk

Comment: I guess this is a bug of knitr, but it should be very easy to get around as you mentioned (use the same `cache.path` for both chunks).